# DIV-image resize nightmare - can't fix it

Tags: css

I've just spent hours trying to fix this but no use.

I have images inside a DIV which move around when I resize the browser (instead of resizing and keeping the same layout, they move downwards).

I want the website to resize but also to keep the aspect ratio of the layout and images up to a certain width - I've managed this with the rest of the site.

**Here is the code:**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.main {
  background-image: url("images/imosec_02.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 497px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>imosec2p</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/imosec_01.gif" height="197" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="main" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="men" id="men">
      <img src="images/imosec_03.gif" height="166" alt=""><img src="images/imosec_04.gif" height="166" alt=""><img src="images/imosec_05.gif" height="166" alt=""><img src="images/imosec_06.gif" height="166" alt=""><img src="images/imosec_07.gif" height="166"
        alt=""><img src="images/imosec_08.gif" height="166" alt="">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please can someone help with this, so stuck

Comment: First of all, as I see, you specified exact height and width in your html layout. This attributes have more weight than css styles in a final html representation.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing this on your css

```
*{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: what that does is it will wrap your image around your div to your likings

Comment: didn't work unfortunately, maybe I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: ttry applying it to your body tag, and change the  height of your img to 100%

Comment: and change your row class to any size that you desire fit

Comment: actually, what i suggest you do, still add what i noted above. take the height define on your div.main class , because i think that is what causing your image to move downwards if I am understanding this correctly

Comment: thanks, sadly this does nothing to the images at the bottom of the page

Comment: take it out i mean,

Answer (score 1):

Try adding id's to each `<img>` element and then using css, set the width to a percentage. This means that the width will change according to the screen size. For example:

```
<img src="hello.png" id="hello-img"/>
```

CSS:

```
#hello-img {width: 30%};
```

The hello image will only take up a 30% of the width of the parent.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: thanks, width was stretching the image, I used max-width: 20% which seemed to work, but only for the first image. I made a new id and css for each image but the others didn't change size

Comment: Make sure you remove the img {max-width: 100%} part because that might override what you are trying to do. Instead, change it to  img {max-width: 20%}

Comment: hi, thanks. this worked - now they seem to resize as well as move down below each other though when resizing

Comment: Try adjusting the max-width to 16% instead. Let me know if this works for you! If it does, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the way:

I used a table and inserted my images into them within the DIV, easy enough.

Here is the code:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```